# Performance issue in Ext js version 6 while displaying search result

Tags: extjs6

We are using tree panel ext js of version 6, fetching the records from database and rendered to the page by search function. While rendering if the rows are more than 200, it is taking more than 15 seconds to display and if we scroll up and down it is hanging. Suggest some ideas to increase the performance.